# Comando spring não encontrado

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Eu instalei o **Spring CLI** em minha maquina recentemente, e configurei o arquivo etc/profile, nele eu já havia configurado meu `JAVA_HOME`, e tentei configurar o `SPRING_HOME`, o fim do arquivo está assim:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk-11.0.5
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export SPRING_HOME=/opt/spring-2.2.5.RELEASE
export PATH=$SPRING_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Se eu entrar em `/opt/spring-2.2.5.RELEASE/bin` e digitar *spring*, ou *spring* , o mesmo executa. Mas se eu tentar usar o comando spring fora deste diretório. Dá uma mensagem dizendo "Comando spring não encontrado" e me da sugestões de instalações.

Alguém pode me explicar o que eu fiz errado?

Comment: rodou source /etc/profile novamente pra pegar o caminho?

Comment: Bem lembrado. Eu cheguei a usar source /etc/profile, e após executar spring novamente funciona, mas se eu fechar o terminal, tenho que usar source /etc/profile novamente. A questão é como eu configurei o Home e o Path não deveria ser possível rodar este comando sempre por qualquer usuário sem ter que usar source /etc/profile toda a vez que eu preciso?

Comment: se você quiser que o comando dure sugiro que coloque ele ( o export ) no /etc/environment

Comment: Excelente sugestão. Muito obrigado. Como eu seto essa pergunta como resolvida?

Comment: mandei minha sugestão como resposta, só marcar lá

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme conversado, sugerida a inclusão da variável de ambiente no escopo global em /etc/environment. Para mais detalhes sobre o funcionamento de variáveis de ambiente:

[Variáveis de ambiente.](https://www.hostinger.com.br/tutoriais/variaveis-de-ambiente-linux/)